# Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, devops

I have deployed python:3.8-slim-buster image to the App Service. Generally it is being run correctly as I can see the processing in the logs, however the health-check mechanism tries to ping the hosted server but it does not respond as it is only code that runs in a loop and process the messages from the queue.
It would be fine, but the application is being killed with the error:

```
Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. 
Stopping site because it failed during startup.
```

Is there either a way to remove this `Waiting for response to warmup request for container` or specify in the dockerfile to respond with OK to those requests?

Currently my dockerfile is a 2 liner, that only copies the scripts and then runs python script.

The code that is inside this script is copied from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send#create-a-python-script-to-receive-events

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
 COPY ./Scripts .
 CMD [ "python3","-u","./calculate.py"]
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: code is inside https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send#create-a-python-script-to-receive-events

Comment: Pls show your dockfile, such as contain `-e environment='Production' -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production'` ...

Comment: @JasonPan added the dockerfile code

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/46401

Comment: Read this link, I think it will help you.

Comment: This works in Azure `-e environment=Production -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production`

Comment: @JasonPan but I'm dotnet core so I don't really have an option to put it anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229676/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-lubu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for that is to either host the script in a server e.g. nodejs or equivalent for given language, or create separate process that will return something for the 80 port.

There also might be a problem with the port configured on default, here is an answer how to fix that case:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1003418/azure-docker-app-error-site-did-not-start-within-expected-time-limit-and-co